# Inheriting from int object

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class that inherits from int, in my class **init** function I am not calling the parent **init** function, but still somehow there is a value when I use the parent (int) methods, which means I think that the parent **init** was also called?

for example:

```
class NumberWithCall(int):
    def __init__(self, number):
        pass

print(NumberWithCall(8))
```

will return 8

I thought that maybe the parent constructor is called implicitly, but in this code I saw it is not:

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print("in parent init")

class son(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print("in son init")

son()
```

will return: in son init

Comment: Immutable types in Python generally do the work in `__new__`, not `__init__`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Comment: you're right, thank you! if I implement the __new__ function in my subclass without calling the super __new__ then it will not return 8 but None

Comment: @EyalGruber: It returns `None` because you didn't *return* anything from it. But yeah, it's essentially impossible to implement a `__new__` without `super` (or equivalently, explicitly calling a parent class's `__new__`) because the raw machinery to make a new instance isn't available at the Python layer *except* through an existing type's `__new__`.

Answer (score 3):

I intend to show you what happens roughly. By the way **I over simplified this**.

first think about implementing `__call__` inside your class. It enables the instance of the class to be callable.

Now we know that classes are instances themselves -> of type `type`:

```
class A:
    pass

print(isinstance(A, type))  # True
```

So there has to be a `__call__` method in "their" class(better to say metaclass) and of course there is one in `type`.

When you put parentheses in front of you class, you are actually calling this method with the given argument (here `8`). What it does, first(here some another things happens but we ignored) calls the `__new__` method with the argument you passed to the `__call__`, this method returns an instance of `int`, then `__init__` will get called as an instance method on the newly created int object.

So the way your class works is because of this:

```
class NumberWithCall(int):
    def __new__(cls, number):
        created_object = super().__new__(cls, number)
        return created_object

    def __init__(self, number):
        print(f'init is called with number={number}')


print(NumberWithCall(8))
```

You inherited this `__new__` from `int` and so yes, as @johnrsharpe pointed out in the comment, *"Immutable types in Python generally do the work in `__new__`, not `__init__`*